# Problem Regarding Linearity of Expectation

Tags: expected-value

Suppose we have a universe consisting of $m$ elements where $k$ of them are of type $1$ and $m-k$ are of the second type. You sample $n$ elements from the universe equally likely without looking. If $Z$ is the number of type $1$ elements in the sample, how can we express the expected value of $Z$?

My approach: $Z$ can be represented a sum of indicator random variables $I_1+I_2+...+I_n$. Thus, $\mathbb{E}(Z) = \mathbb{E}(I_1+I_2+...+I_n) = \mathbb{E}(I_1) + \mathbb{E}(I_2) + ...+\mathbb{E}(I_n)$.

Since any element in the universe is of type $1$ with probability $\frac{k}{m}$, $\mathbb{E}(Z) = \frac{k \cdot n}{m}$

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  As a sanity check, note that if $n=m$ you get the value $k$ which of course you should.

Comment: @lulu that makes so much sense. Thanks!